# Are there any strong objections to the creation of the neutrality tag?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

On [Which of the BBC's postwar "many versions of neutrality" are candidates for one which "meets the competing needs of Kyiv and Moscow"?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/72170/16047) I have added a new [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality) tag.

Neutrality is an oft-used but difficult to unambiguously define term to describe a country's foreign policy (or lack thereof) as a country may remain historically neutral for the most part but take a stance on certain specific issues, e.g. Switzerland.

Nonetheless there are countries that are generally agreed to be neutral, and also countries that may absolutely not be neutral in general but strive to remain neutral in specific situations, e.g. India on the Russo-Ukraine situation.

I propose that the political neutrality or non-neutrality of a country can and will be the topic of questions in Politics SE and that a neutrality tag will help link them together making it easier for one post to refer to situations described and documented in another post or to highlight and/or draw from previous arguments here.

Just [searching neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutrality) pulls up 172 posts, but [searching neutrality is:question](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutrality+is%3Aquestion) only 34 suggesting that it would not be difficult nor disruptive to retag an estimated half of those that are specifically about neutrality.

Are there any strong objections to the creation of this tag?

Comment: Seems like a good idea to me, see for example [Wikipedia's page on the concept of a neutral country](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neutral_country).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

While I have no objection to a [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality) tag, it is important to distinguish between [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality) as a position for international relations and the existing questions for [net-neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/net-neutrality), many of which have not been tagged ([at least 7 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22net+neutrality%22+is%3Aq+-%5Bnet-neutrality%5D)), and [gender-neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/gender-neutrality) (also [at least 7 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutral*+gender+is%3Aq+-%5Bgender-neutrality%5D)). Several others mentioning neutrality are not about neutrality in international relations.

After extensive filtering, [13 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22neutrality%22+-%22net+neutrality%22+is%3Aq+-green+-%5Blegislative-process%5D+-demarchy+-%22civil+service%22+-%22platform+neutrality%22+-islam+-%22fast+lane%22+-%22toward+neutrality%22+-%5Bterminology%5D+-%5Bneutrality%5D) (using "neutrality") remain as likely candidates for re-tagging for [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality). **Note:** The filter removes questions tagged [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality) so the number of questions will change during the re-tagging process.

Among questions that use "neutral" to describe a country's position, there are [at least 8 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutral+-neutrality+is%3Aq+-%5Bneutrality%5D+countr*+-gender+-democracy+-birth*+-nazism+-maoist*+-%22i+am%22+-carbon+-climate+-venezuela+-dc+-%5B*media%5D+-opinion+-religion+-%5Bidentity*%5D+-%5Bbudget%5D) for re-tagging (again that number will change during re-tagging).

It appears that more questions use "neutrality" (than "neutral"), when asking about a country's position in international relations, and both "neutrality" and "neutral" are used more frequently to refer to a country's position in international relations.

Therefore, I suggest the tag [country-neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/country-neutrality) be created and [neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/neutrality) be made a synonym of that tag.

Suggested excerpt for [country-neutrality](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/country-neutrality):

> Questions about a country's position in international relations with respect to war, military alliances, etc. Use with a country tag.

Comment: Maybe in this case [neutral-country] would be a more descriptive tag?

Comment: @JJJ - Or [country-neutrality] as a describing a type of neutrality. I notice a few questions appear to refer to a potential [legislative-neutrality]; such as, https://politics.stackexchange.com/q/43949/26455. This would be consistent with the pattern set by [net-neutrality]. I guess in retrospect [neutrality] may be a little broad.

Comment: Using "neutral -neutrality is:q" adds [88 questions](https://politics.stackexchange.com/search?q=neutral+-neutrality+is%3Aq) to be investigated; some of which refer to neutrality in international relations.

Comment: @RickSmith You raise important points, thank you for your answer! Yes this does need to be done carefully. [Here's an example](https://astronomy.meta.stackexchange.com/a/703/7982) of a slightly tricky retagging campaign; it's certainly doable, what I did first was *state the algorithm or "scripted task"* that humans would implement, then limit the execution to N questions per week so as not to flood the active question queue.

Comment: @uhoh Great idea. I vote for [neutrality], since it is the most common term **in the context of this site**. I would certainly search for that when I tag; not for [country-neutrality] or [neutral-country]. Just specify on the tag usage or description that this is not for [legislative-neutrality], [net-neutrality], etc.

Comment: @TimurShtatland - [country-neutrality] being the most common use for neutrality, the [neutrality] tag would likely be made a synonym of [country-neutrality]. When entering a tag name on a question or the "tags" page, `neutrality` would show the excerpt for [country-neutrality]. In the search bar, entering `[neutrality]` would show questions tagged [country-neutrality]. (This is not my first rodeo!) I expect I will revise my answer this weekend, to finalize my recommendation, and, if there are no objections, proceed with re-tagging as time and circumstances permit.

Comment: @RickSmith Glad to learn from experienced rodeo riders! :) Thanks for the explanations, and +1, of course.